# Why function is called before printing a statement?

Tags: c, function, printf

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int func(int x){
   printf("Print\n");
   return x;
 }
 void main(){
   printf("The value of x is %d",func(50)); /* Print is printed first then the value of x */
   return 0;
 }
```

Output for this program is:

```
Print
The value of x is 50
```

So my question is why function printing `Print` after that it is printing `The value of x is 50`. Why `The value of x is` not printed before since the function is called after the statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us analyze the flow of your program.

1. `main()` is being called.
2. `printf()` is being called.

   2.1 While evaluating the arguments of `printf()`, the `func(50)` function call is encountered

   2.2 `func(50)` function starts to execute. It prints `Print` and returns `x` [50]
3. finally, the `printf()` in `main()` looks like `printf("The value of x is %d",50);` [50 is return value of function call `func(50)`]
4. second prints occurs, printing `The value of x is 50`

So, your output screen will look like

```
Print
The value of x is 50
```

Note: As already mentioned in comments, use `int main()` instead of `void main()`. Otherwise, `return 0` is meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

```
func(50)
```

is a parameter to the function `printf()` so the parameter is getting executed first and `%d` in the first paramter of `printf()` expects a value which needs to be printed and that is provided by the second agrument.
So the function call `func(50)` happens first printing out `Print` from the function `func()` and later the `printf` in the `main()` gets executed.

```
printf("The value of x is %d",func(50));
```

func(50) --> Prints out `Print` and returns 50

So now the printf() in main() will look like:

```
printf("The value of x is %d",50);
```

Eventually printing out

```
Print
The value of x is 50
```